# The best practice for 2 repo depends on each other

Tags: go-modules

I have two microservices, each of which has its own repo.
repo1 depends on repo2/entityA
repo2 depends on repo1/entityB

Some possible solutions I can think of:

1. Make another repo3 to put entityA and entityB, then repo1 and repo2
   depends only on repo3.
2. In repo1, make a seperate go module for entityB.
   In repo2, make a seperate go module for entityA.
   repo1 (except entityA module) depends on go module entityB, which is in repo2.
   repo2 (except entityB module) depends on go module entityA, which is in repo1.

What's the best practice for such case?

Answer (score 0):

I this case, it sounds like the common dependencies (`entityA` and `entityB`) should be in a third repo/module. So, you would have 3 modules instead of the second option which requires 4 (2 for each repo).

It's best practice to only have a single module per repository. More than one module in a repo is a bit more work to maintain and more difficult to reason about. It's definitely possible to do, but generally avoid it when possible.

Note: when you want to make updates to the shared dependencies and the consumer repos at the same time, you can use `replace` to get a nice local development experience. Of course, the common dependency would need to be updated *first*, before the consumer module.